# How to add urls to appCache when using Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

How can you add action urls to appcache? I can't find anything about this, so I am afraid that it isn't possible?

For example, to add urls to the appCache files, you will do:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/index.aspx
/someFile.js
```

But in asp.net MVC project where you are using Razor, you don't have the .aspx file extentions, but rather action urls.
Is it possible to some how add this to the manifest appCache?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break up your static appcache projected into a MVC oriented one.
This example is your best bet to a [Solution](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/mvc-and-the-html5-application-cache/59)